Using Gitlab sca tools - Dependency scanning for CPP
I have downloaded CPP sourcecode and dependency libraries.
Being opensource, I would like to perform sca (software composition analysis) scanning in Gitlab.
How to I do so?
step1. Uploaded the source code into the repo with the folders created.
step2. Untar the files.
step3. build the source code
step4. in gitlab-ci.yml, include the template auto-ci.gitlab-ci.yml file
When running the pipeline, the sca scan will happen automatically and the vulnerability can be found in Analysis folder (?)
Is this the correct steps? Please advise.
